# Spring cloud kubernetes loadbalancer and resttemplate

Tags: spring, kubernetes

I am trying to call a microservice through spring cloud discoveryclient with load balanced resttemplate. When I call the service (xyz) from service abc with resttemplate.exchange method, two requests are submitted to the service and one for each of the POD. The services are running in a Kubernetes cluster and there are two replicas running for the service being called. Both pods are getting the request. Due to client side load balancing, the load balanced template should send request to one pod at a time.

Below are configuration details:

In bootstrap.yml

spring:
application:
name: abc
cloud:
kubernetes:
discovery:
enabled: true
all-namespaces: true
reload:
enabled: 'true'
enabled: 'true'
loadbalancer:
ribbon:
enabled: 'false'

Load balanced rest templates are loaded as:

@Configuration
public class LoadRestTemplate {

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoadRestTemplate.class);
@LoadBalanced
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

}
The target service is called from service abc from a class which has the following snippet of code:

```
@Autowired private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;
@LoadBalanced @Autowired private RestTemplate restTemplate;
String baseUrl = "http://xyz" + "/envvar?value=MNC";
    try {
        response = restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
      }
```

When I tail the logs of both PODs, both are receiving the requests. But when I invoke this service xyz from POSTMAN, only one request is submitted to the service. In the entire cluster there is only one service with the name of xyz.

The version of spring cloud is 2022.0.3

Comment: The issue was caused by using the discovery client from service layer. It should have been done from controller layer. When the other service is called from controller layer, the load balancing was happening properly.